# The text File is not load in a TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, textbox

Here is my Code :

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string tempfolder = Server.MapPath("~/SampleFiles/" + filename);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(tempfolder);
        TextBox3.Text = filename;
        Label6.Text = "File Uploaded succesfully";
    }
    else
    {
        Label6.Text = "Error in Uploading";
    }
}
```

but this code gives only a file name .
i want to load a contents of a text file on a textbox.

Comment: `TextBox3.Text = filename;`  You are storing the filename of the file in the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one seems pretty obvious. You're setting `TextBox3.Text=filename`. And `filename` is the name of the file. Let's use [`File.ReadAllText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the contents of the file.

Try this...

```
//assuming tempfolder has the path to your saved file
string contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(tempfolder);
TextBox3.Text = contents;
```

Comment: thanks mason
i using a filename in place of tempfolder...

string loadlines = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);
but after the change it works.

Comment: That only works so long as the file is uploaded to the same folder as your page. Are you sure you even need to save the uploaded file on your filesystem? It might be better to just read it into memory if you don't need to keep the file.